# Android paging library java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MainThreadExecutor required

Tags: android, kotlin, pagedlist, android-paging

I'm using Android paging library `androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.0.0` to build a list. The problem is that when I want to build `PagedList` (`LivePagedList` works well) i have an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MainThreadExecutor required
at androidx.paging.PagedList$Builder.build(PagedList.java:355)
```

But I don't see that `setMainThreadExecutor` method available, there is only `setFetchExecutor`:

```
    val result = list.filter { it.desc?.contains(query, ignoreCase = true) == true }
    val dataSource = MyDataSource(result)
    val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    val pagedList: PagedList<MyDetails> = PagedList.Builder<Int, MyDetails>(dataSource, 500).setFetchExecutor { mainHandler.post(it) }
                .build()
```

Who knows what's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the source, you get this exception if the executor set with [`setNotifyExecutor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.Builder.html#setNotifyExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)) is null. I don't see you call that.

I agree the exception message is somewhat misleading.

For source reference I used [this](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/support/paging/common/src/main/java/androidx/paging/PagedList.java#355). It's not exactly the same but I believe the androidx version behaves the same here.